# SSRS report to print labels from a roll

Tags: reporting-services, printing, labeling

Does anyone have any experience of creating a report that will print labels that are on a roll?

I can see plenty of examples for a sheet of labels, but nothing with any great detail regarding a roll.

Would the best method be to set the report page up to have 1 column and then adjust the size of the page to be the size of the label?

There will be different info on each label, and a varying number of labels per print.

So basically set up the report to mirror the label size and then repeat pages depending on how many labels need printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to set your report to have the same page size as your label then design the report as normal.

As for producing multiple labels, you can either

1. have a single dataset containing all the info you need for all labels and group by whatever makes each label unique (e.g. a label number). Then add a page break on the row group property to put a break between each, or ..
2. you could create a subreport that just handles a single label and then have a master report that with a table control with a single 'cell' and the subreport inside that cell. You would then pass the parameters to the subreport from the main dataset. I think you've seen a similar answer I posted about printing sheets of labels, if you follow that then it should get you most of the way there.

Option 1 is probably the simplest method...
**Step-by-Step for option 1**
In this example I've used the Microsoft sample database WideWorldImporters, just so I could get some names and addresses.

Step 1: Write your query to get your data. In my example I used the following..

```
SELECT top 10 o.OrderID, c.CustomerName, c.DeliveryAddressLine1, c.DeliveryAddressLine2, cty.CityName, c.DeliveryPostalCode
  FROM [Sales].[Orders] o
    JOIN Sales.Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    JOIN Application.Cities cty on c.DeliveryCityID = cty.CityID
ORDER BY OrderID
```

This just gives me the order number, company name and address.

Step 2: Create a new report. I'm using Visual Studio but the process is almost identical in Report Builder if you use that.

- Create a new, blank report
- Add a datasource and dataset containing your query from step 1
- Select the 'body' and set the `size` property to your label size. I used 100mm, 40mm
- Select the 'report' and set the `PageSize` property to the same values as above and the margins to 0

[image]
[image]

Step 3: Add a table to contain the data

- Add the new table
- Delete the header row
- Delete the last column (I have a two column label in my example but obviously up to you)
- Select the table (tablix) using the grey table handle (top left of the table) and then set the dataset property to the name of the dataset you created earlier
- Add enough rows to contain all your data, in my case 6 in total
- In the RowGroups panel under the main report design, right-click the details rowgroup and choose `Add Group => Parent Group`. Select `OrderID` as the field to group on and click OK
- Remove the newly added column and if prompted choose 'remove column only'
- Right-Click the `(OrderID)` Row group and go to Group properties, click Page Break and choose 'between'
- Set  each row to contain your data until you end up with something like....

[image]

Clean up the formatting and that should be it. One label per page and each page set to your label size.

You may need to adjust the layout slightly to adjust for margins etc but this should give you a good start.

Comment: Having difficulty setting up a label design and using a row group. I cannot use a row group without having a table, or list that requires at least one column. I need to group on an order number, and then have a name and address printed in a label format.

Comment: If you r dataset contains order# name and address then create a table, Add a row group for Order#. Add detail rows as required for Name and address. In the row group properties set page breaks between. Remove all whitespace from the report so the table fills the 'page'. If you can;t work out what I mean, let me know and I'll post a full answer.

Comment: A full answer would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll see if I can put something together this evening, work is a bit hectic at the moment

Comment: Thanks for that, have managed to set this report up this morning, now just the small matter of getting the labels to print! Much appreciated.

Comment: One issue I have, is the address is a string with line feeds. I have replaced these with a carriage return and a line feed, so the address now appears in the correct format. However, as the address varies from potentially 2 address lines, to potentially 7, how can I ensure the address stays within the given size for the label?

Comment: You should ask a new question but you can set the address "cell" `Can Grow` property to false. Although that will mean if the address is too long, it will chop the end off. If this does not solve the problem. Post a new question specifically about this issue.